# how to call system() from a specific directory?

Tags: c, linux

I need my program go to some specific directory then run

`system( ... );` there and get me back where I was before. How can I do it?

Comment: windows and linux, but more interesting - for linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the `cd` in your `system` call:

```
system("cd wherever; command");
```

The whole string gets passed to `sh(1)`, so you can do any normal shell things in there.  Since it's in a subshell, the working directory of your program won't be changed.

Comment: However, you will perhaps construct the string passed to `system(3)`. Be careful. Think of a malicious user claiming to have a directory named `foo;rm -rf $HOME` (he could have a directory with spaces, semicolons, dollars in its name, even if that is suspicious).

Comment: Well, the OP said "specific directory", so hopefully that's a solvable problem.

Comment: It is solvable, but the OP has to care about that.

Comment: `system("cd directory && command");` would be better, because then the command is executed only if the `cd` succeeds. `system("cd directory || exit $? ; command");` is another way to write the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux and Posix systems, the `system(3)` function is implemented above [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and others. You could use the [chdir(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/chdir.2.html) syscall to change the current directory. You could use [getcwd(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) to retrieve (and memoize) it before changing it. (you could also call `getcwd` and `chdir` before `system`, then restore the original current directory with another `chdir`).

I suggest reading a good book like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) and [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/), they have several chapters to answer your questions.

<sup>Don't expect a forum to explain all this to you. Read books.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Use [chdir](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) before calling system. You can even use [getcwd](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) before `chdir` to return to the directory after system.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to specific directory with [chdir](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/chdir/)
2. Run system(...) (as Basile said, if system is taking user-defined variables, make sure to sanitize them)

When the program executes system(..), it will be in the changed directory. After system(...), it will be in the changed directory. When the program exits, it will be in the original directory.

Comment: But your process stays in the new directory. (The invoking program, usually a shell, did not `chdir` implicitly since current directory is a local property of each process)